# can't access the controller function(s) in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi my folder sturcture is like this

```
controllers/user/registration/register.php
```

Inside the register.php controller there is let say for test index function saying 'hello world'.But i cant access the folder index through browser.

My base_url is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/new/';
```

But while i write

```
localhost/new/index.php/user/registration/register/index
```

I got an error

```
The page you requested was not found.
```

what is weird is, I can access the controller fxn of user folder but cant access the controller fxn inside registration folder .And for default controller i have 'home.php'

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I just want to access the controller/user/registration/register/index fxn which says 'hello world' but it says an error-'The page you requested was not found'.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it needs any, but do you have any routes for the register controller? You could try adding one to the top of your routes anyway to see if works for you `$route['user/registration/register/index'] = 'user/registration/register/index';`

Comment: thanks for your help but i did'nt work i dont think its routing problem too in routes.php .Why is that i can access the controller fxn insider controller/user folder but can't inside controller/user/registratio folder

Comment: Are you extending the routing class, or doing any custom routing? What version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Codeigniter only supports a single level directory structure for Controllers.

Try this link below for Multi Level Subfolder Controller in CodeIgniter :

[Multi Level Subfolder Controller in CodeIgniter](http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: Really... the documentation says otherwise. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders

Comment: ok i got it.I did review in my previous projects and find out that i have never used multi level subfolder for controller.I think this is the root cause of my error here.Thanks all of you.you all were very helpful.

Comment: But, it is possible. Go through the above link Sid.

Comment: Jeemusu, documentation is saying about the default controller for the sub folders. It has not mentioned how many sub folder does it support over uri.

Comment: It would be better if you explain some important thing from the link which u have given there.......

Answer (score 1):

Ok after writing some hunch code in my test project ,finally it worked in my case
So here it goes
I follow this link Multi Level Subfolder Controller in CodeIgniter(thanks to K u s h)

```
http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/
```

and copy the code and paste in my new/application/core/MY_Router.php as told in that link
and an error came to me like this

```
Call to undefined method CI_Router::CI_Router() in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\application\core\MY_Router.php
```

So i changed a little portion of that code to

```
//  Function MY_Router()
//  {
//      parent::CI_Router();
//  }
   public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
   }
```

And after i was able to access the controllers/user/registration/register.php index fxn

It worked in my case.Thanks to all